# Troubleshooting oracle database errors from cloud application

Tags: oracle-11g, java, cloud

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue that presents as different database errors such as, ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded or Unable to create DB Connection.  I have reviewed the PLSQL to determine if cursors were left open and all are closed even if there is an error.

The java application and background are as follows:
The original application was a 3-tiered system:

> GUI app. -> server app -> 11g Oracle database

The enhancement was to add an API service in a Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) environment.
So this architecture was like this:

> Close Function: GUI app -> Server App -> API service -> Database.
>
> All other Functions: GUI app -> Server App -> Database.

This was put into production and run for a week without any database issues described above.
Then another enhancement was added in which the API Service communicates with several other services all in PCF in which 2 communicate with the same oracle database.  Now during heavy volume we are getting these database errors.

It seems to me that the Oracle database cannot keep up with the requests from these additional services.  But how can I demonstrate that.  We have AppD configured for the servers but not the database.  Are there queries that I can run in the prod env. that shows that these PCF applications are causing the issue?  Or should I look in another area?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**
I created a query that shows the total open cursor by sessionID
This is the query:

```
select b.sid, b.username, b.osuser, b.status, sum(a.value) total_opened_current_cursors
from sys.v_$statname c,  
     sys.v_$sesstat a,
     sys.v_$session b    
 where a.statistic#=c.statistic# and 
      b.sid=a.sid and 
      c.name in ('opened cursors current') and 
      (b.username is not null or b.username <> '' )   
group by b.sid, b.username, b.osuser
order by total_opened_current_cursors desc
```

Now, I need to link the sessionID with the application that has this session.
The **osuser** for the top ones is NULL.
Also, most of the sessions' status are **INACTIVE**
How to identify the application to the session?
Secondly, is the session is inactive, which I thought meant that no query is happending so why are there open cursors?

**UPDATE**
SORRY I ADDED THIS UPDATE TO THE ANSWER...SHOULD HAVE ADDED IT HERE
So, I wrote a query that returns the top 10 sessions with the highest open cursors

```
select * 
FROM 
(
select b.sid, b.username, b.osuser, b.status, sum(a.value) total_opened_current_cursors
from sys.v_$statname c,  
     sys.v_$sesstat a,
     sys.v_$session b    
 where a.statistic#=c.statistic# and 
      b.sid=a.sid and 
      c.name in ('opened cursors current') and 
      (b.username is not null or b.username <> '' )   
group by b.sid, b.username, b.osuser,  b.status
order by total_opened_current_cursors desc
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```

I found the SQL_TEXT that accounts for most of the open cursors...by far! (87%)
So, how do I find the query that calls this SQL?
There are at least 5 services that hit the database. Some of the services call PLSQL stored procedures some call raw SQL text.  The query that accounts for the open cursors is listed as a **SELECT** statement.  Does that mean it is NOT a stored procedure?  Or can this **SELECT** be called within the stored procedures.
How do I find the connection that uses this session?

Comment: the max number of open cursors is set at a session level, so you have a session opening more than the limit. What is the current limit (the Oracle default is low, by the way). There’s no real harm in upping the parameter significantly temporarily while you continue to investigate. You can find the problematic sessions using the v$sesstat view and v$open_cursor.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded is almost always an application error.  I'll put a large wager down that some part of the Java middle tier is failing to close a ResultSet in every case.  That causes it to leak cursors and will eventually cause this error.  You can increase the `max_open_cursors` setting in Oracle so that the cursor leak hits the limit more slowly.  You may want to combine that with more aggressive restarts of the middle tier and/or recycling of the connection pool as a temporary measure.  But the right answer would be to figure out where the application is leaking cursors and plug the leak.

Do you have any additional logging around the unable to create a connection error?  It is possible that you're hitting the maximum number of connections specified by your `sessions` setting (and the `processes` setting on which it depends).  If you really need to support more connections, you can always bump that up or move some of the connections over to shared server connections if they're using dedicated server connections today.  But I'd be concerned given the cursor error that the middle tier is also leaking connections.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the number of open cursors based on the application?  During a close function there can be as many as 3 applications that query the database.

Comment: I looked at the legacy application and the result sets are closed.  The other 3 PCF applications use Spring Boot to connect to the database. From my understanding, closing connections and result sets do not have to be explicitly closed. JDBCTemplate closes these connections/result sets. The PLSQL added has an additional cursor which is closed on success and exception.

Comment: @GloriaSantin - `max_open_cursors` controls the number of cursors that are open per session (i.e. per connection).  The default of 50 should be plenty though you can up that to 65535 if you want.  You should be able to use `v$open_cursors` and `v$sesstat` to track down what cursors are being left open which hopefully lets you track it down to a particular application.  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:685336504294 AskTom has a much more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Just a basic question. These queries must take place in realtime of the max open cursor error, correct?  Are there any tables that I can query for errors that happened in the past?

Comment: @GloriaSantin - I don't know of a history table.  When you're looking for a cursor leak, though, you should see the number of open cursors increasing slowly over time in a session (assuming your sessions are relatively long-lived which is the normal case).  So you don't need to be getting the error to watch in real time as different sessions leak cursors to figure out which statements are getting leaked.

Comment: OK. So, I need to develop a query that shows the session, max cursors and open cursors.  Run it periodically to id the session that is creating this leak.

Comment: @GloriaSantin - I'd expect that there would be several sessions that were leaking cursors.  You'd want to see which statements were used to open those cursors and then trace those statements back to a particular piece of application code that is leaking the cursors.

Comment: I wrote a query (see above under the UPDATE statement) that shows the sessions with open cursors. However, the status of these sessions are all **INACTIVE**.  My understanding of an inactive session is that it is not querying the database.  So does that mean that those are the sessions with leaking cursors?

Comment: @GloriaSantin - Most sessions are going to be INACTIVE most of the time.  That means the session isn't running a statement at that instant.  But they can still have open cursor handles.  You'd want to see which statements are most commonly left open.

Comment: OK.  I found the query that accounts for most of the open cursors for the session that has the most open cursors.  I have the SQL_Text.  Now, I need to find the application that calls this query.  I updated my quandary above..

Comment: @GloriaSantin - I'd think that you'd just search your source code (plus `all_source` if your stored procedures aren't in source control) to find where the statement is coming from.  A stored procedure can't leak cursors.  If you happen to open and return a `ref cursor` to the caller, the calling application can leak a cursor that was opened in a stored procedure.  `v$session` may have enough information to tell you which application is involved depending on how your environment is configured.

Comment: The values in the v$session (Program, modele, client_identifier, client_info) are all null.  The SQL identified, a SELECT query, is leaking cursors as exactly as you describe. The SELECT is within a stored procedure.  The select is used to store and return a ref cursor. So, I should look in the application for the leaking cursor.  Why can't the stored procedure leak cursors?

Comment: @GloriaSantin - You'd need to look at the application calling the procedure to see where it is failing to close the cursor.  A stored proc alone can't leak a cursor because Oracle knows when the cursor goes out of scope that it can be closed.  If a calling application runs a select statement (or calls a proc that returns a ref cursor), Oracle doesn't know that the application is done with it until the application closes the cursor.  When the application fails to inform Oracle by closing the cursor, you get a cursor leak.

Comment: A colleague of mine.  Ran the application using the stored procedure that returns the ref cursor from the stored procedure that supposedly is leaking cursors.  He noticed that the cursor number go up and go down once the screen populated. This might be a volume issue.  In production, they don't see the problem on the weekends when the volume is low but during certain days when the volume is high the open cursors happens a lot.

Comment: @GloriaSantin - That's the normal behavior.  The procedure opened the cursor and returned the handle to the caller.  The open cursor count increased by 1.  The application fetched the data to populate the screen and closed the cursor and the count went back down.  If the application never closed the cursor, you'd be hitting the error very very quickly.  Most likely, in a small fraction of cases (commonly various error scenarios), the step of closing the cursor gets skipped and you get a leak.  When you've leaked enough cursors, you eventually get the error.

Comment: THANKS...AS ALWAYS! Will work on looking into that...